# DocuSign Express certificate in the development

Tags: java, pdf, acrobat, docusignapi

I am developing Java-based application with embedded signing. It works just fine with a Dev account in Demo without digital certificates (REST API). We must use digital certificates (DocuSign Express). I understand that I have to add request properties “X-DocuSign-Signature” and “X-DocuSign-Thumbprint” to all my REST API calls. I realize that to use digital certificate authentication in the production we have to coordinate with our account management but we need a working version in the development first. What values am I supposed to assign to these properties in the development, using my dev account (in demo.docusign.net) to avoid “Signature is invalid” in the final PDF document?

Comment: By default PDFs should validate in Reader.  What message do you get in Reader?  Also, it seems that you may have two different features confused.  Which one of these do you need?  DocuSign Express Digital Signatures causes signed PDFs to include a digital signature using DocuSign's CA registered in California.  The X-DocuSign-Signature and X-DocuSign-Thumbprint headers are for securing your API requests.

Comment: Embedded signing without DocuSign Express is OK, signatures are valid in Acrobat Reader. We need documents to be digitally signed with DocuSign Express (we paid  for  it). I checked “DocuSign Express” in the template. Signing works fine; download from demo.docusign.net shows “Signature is valid”.  When I get the same document using API, PDF Reader shows “Signature contains incorrect data. SigDict /Contents illegal data.” I used the same requests as for non-digitally-signed version: <baseURL>/envelopes/< envelopeId>/documents/combined, headers X-DocuSign-Authentication, Content-Type, Accept

Comment: Interesting - okay.  If you don't use /combined do you get the same behavior?  I ask because /combined gives you one PDF including the Certificate of Completion.  Since the signer technically did not sign that combined document it might be breaking the hash.  If you instead retrieve individual documents I imagine it'll be okay.

Comment: Alas, after I got rid of “/combined” and retrieved the document and the Certificate of Completion separately, I still got “Signature contains incorrect, unrecognized, corrupted or suspicious data” on the signed document. When a document is downloaded from demo.docusign.net, all signatures are valid. Retrieved summary looks good in PDF. Maybe I miss some settings? 
Use the New DocuSign Experience: No
Use DocuSign Winter ’15 Signing Experience Now: unchecked
Template identity: Email, DC. Summary shows Signer Certificate Applied:
Issuer: DocuSign Express Digital Signature

Comment: One more thing: even when I was using “/combined”, I didn’t include flag certificate=true; only the main document was included in the resulting file, without Certificate of Completion. My setting for “Attach Certificate of Completion to the Envelope PDF” in the Preferences is false. Can switching between classic and new DocuSign experience play a role? Right now I am in classic because of need to use Digital Certificates. Originally my templates were created in “new” demo docusign…

Comment: Hi Jeff, you were right that I confused Digital Signatures with Certificate-based authentication. I need DocuSign Express. In Requiring Digital Signatures and Certificates quick start, I noticed “The Allow recipient(s) to edit the document(s) option cannot be selected” requirement. How to change this setting for embedded signing? I could not find this envelope parameter in Sending and Signing Options. Also I saw “finally the certificate is applied to the envelope (not to each document).” I am just going through all Restrictions and Limitations trying to catch a culprit…